# Opencart categories too slow

Tags: opencart

In open cart admin panel, after adding around 1k products, i'm not able to take the category section. I takes a lot of time to load the category and once loaded, when i try to save or delete a category, it takes too long and shows me 500 error. Is there anything i can do to improve the speed. The other sections in admin panel, loads fine. The problem is only for category section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=5077) is what you are looking for

Comment: This is some good advice, I would also enabled cache, memcache, APC and do some server tweaks to avoid crashing of the PHP application of OpenCart - it is not server intensive even with 1000 products. Check your environment too.

Comment: First of all this is a problem of slow/overloaded server. Recently I was working on an eshop with 5k products and over 200 categories while only frontend was slightly slow but a product count removal plugin helped a lot. However there was no problem within the administration. Even it could be slow there is no reason for error 500 (server internal error) unless this error is thrown by the server as a response to server timeout - which again is about very slow/overloaded server.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The Pagination Extension solved the issue.